About a special way to compute orbifold fundamental group.
I find a lecture note about orbifold here.
In section 1.3, the author provides a method to compute orbifold fundamental group. I make a repetition as follows.

Let $Q$ be a orbifold, and $\widehat{Q}$ denote the complement in $|Q|$(the underlying space of orbifold $Q$) of the strata of codimension $\geq 2$. Orbifold fundamental group $\pi_1^{orb}(Q,x_0)$ can be computed by adding generators and
relations to $\pi_1(\widehat{Q},x_0)$.
New generators:
1.For each component $T$ of a codimension 2 stratum in interior of $|Q|$,
choose a loop $\alpha_T$ starting at $x_0$ which makes a small loop around $T$.
Let $n(T)$ be the order of the cyclic group labeling $T$.
2.Suppose $P$ is a codimension 2 stratum contained in $M \cap N$ (so that $P$
is a corner reflector). Let $m(P)$ be the label on $P$ (so that the dihedral
group at $P$ has order $2m(P)$).
3.For each mirror $M$ and each homotopy class of paths
$M$ from $x0$ to $M$
introduce a new generator $\beta_{(M,\gamma_M)}$.
Relations:

$[\alpha_T]^{n(T)}=1$.
$[\beta_{(M,\gamma_M)}]^2=1$.
$[\beta_{(M,\gamma_M)}\beta_{(N,\gamma_N)}]^{m(P)}=1$. Here $P$ is a component of $\overline{M} \cap \overline{N}$ and $\gamma_M$ and $\gamma_N$ are homotopic as paths from $x_0$ to $P$.


I believe this algorithm provide a good way to compute orbifold fundamental groups. I am interested in the details of the proof regarding this algorithm, while I can't prove it. Any reference would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.
